# Cannot convert instance argument type System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MyModel> to System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper

Tags: razor, sitecore

I am trying to use the following built-in Sitecore helper in Razor:

`@Html.Sitecore().Field("FieldName")`

There is a red squiggly line under Html, with the issue being the following:
`Cannot convert instance argument type System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MyModel> to System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`.

My razor view is using MyModel as the model bound to the view. But I'm confused as to why it thinks I am trying to convert to a different type? I've tried specifying the namespaces:

- `@System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.Sitecore()`, or
- `@System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper.Sitecore()`

but `.Sitecore()` is not recognized as a valid method. I have a `@using` reference for Sitecore.Mvc in my view. This is actually happening all across my project, for every `@Html.Sitecore()` reference, they are all getting the same issue - just different model types. I checked the references in my project but I do not see any warning signs.

Comment: If you deploy the code does it run? Is it just a VS warning that is the issue? How is `Sitecore.MVC.dll` referenced in your project? Have you set `Copy Local=false` on the reference?

Comment: @jammykam it did not prevent the code from running. When I set copy local to false it goes away - why is that? If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Mmm... that's strange, I was expecting the opposite  (that you already set copy local = false) since I've seen that issue before https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/20/excluding-sitecore-assemblies-from-deployment/ so don't know why it works the opposite way!